# Tag version check between two pipelines azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two CI pipelines in azure devops:

1. CI pipeline to train models
2. CI pipeline to score/predict/inference new data

Both of these pipelines are triggered when a PR is created on a specific branch. I have enabled "Tag Builds" on succeed with $build.BuildNumber format. I beleive if the builds are successful, they are given some tags.

I have a release pipeline, what I want to do is to check if the tag/buildNumber for 1st and 2nd CI pipelines are same or not. If not, the release pipeline should fail.

The problem is I cant find any tag information of the CI pipelines here is what I see after a build is succeeded.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that. It is not possible to check if two or more tags are valid based on some logic in devops. So, we ended up using bash task and git commands to check if tags are valid (using regex).